# jQuery hover function

Tags: jquery, hover

Hi I am trying to create a jquery function that fades all other divs when one of the div is clicked on. My code isn't working and I'm not sure how to properly write it. Here is what I have so far:

```
$("#slider div.popup").hover(
var ind = $(this).index();

$("#slider div.popup").each(function() {
    if ($(this).index() != ind) {
        //fades all other .popup divs
        $(this).animate({
            opacity: 0
        });
    }
}), $("#slider div.popup").each(function() {
    if ($(this).index() != ind) {
        //unfades all other .popup divs
        $('span', this).animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
    }
}

));
```

**There is also an example here** : http://jsfiddle.net/7j3mk/

Can someone give me guidance on how to get this code working?

Comment: Your JavaScript syntax is not correct: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var*: Here is a corrected version: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/7j3mk/2/ However, it seems that the mouse events are not raised if the element is transparent, so I'm wondering how you want to show another div after they have been hidden.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beside the wrong syntax you use for the hover method (*it takes two functions as parameters*)
You need to use the [`.not()` <sup>docs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/not) method

```
$("#slider div.popup").hover( function(){
    $("#slider div.popup").not(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 0
        });
}, function(){
    $("#slider div.popup").not(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
});
```

**updated** example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/7j3mk/11/

Comment: ahh thanks I was wondering if there was a function like this in jquery.

Comment: No, he doesn't *need* to use the `not` method, there are many different ways of doing the same thing.

Comment: @Gaby hmm not I don't know if this should be mentioned in a new question but if I mouse to another div all the other divs flash into view before disappearing again.I understand this is just how the function works because on mouseout event. Is there a smooth way of doing this so that the other divs don't flash?

Comment: @Guffa, yes of-course there are other ways.. It was the easiest translation i could suggest tat did what the OP was asking.

Comment: @Ima, updated answer. I am now also using the [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method to stop the current animation. Otherwise they are queued and so it does the flicker. (*added updated jsfiddle as well*)

Comment: @Gaby aka G.Petriolo: Well, actually the OP asked about how to get the code working, not about some other code that does the same thing. ;)

Comment: @Guffa, hadn't seen your answer. Yes your code is *exactly* what the OP asked for.. but i was faster :p

Answer (score 1):

try this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/7j3mk/9/)

```
$("#slider div.popup").hover(function(){
    $('.popup').animate({
            opacity: 0
        });
    $(this).animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
},function(){
    $('.popup').animate({
            opacity: 1
        });
})
```

Comment: +1 oh wow thats really smart. I would have never thought to do that. genius thinking

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in your code:

1. You have forgotten the function wrappers around the code for the event handlers.
2. The variable `ind` is only defined in the first function, you need to define it in the second also.
3. You have a `span` selector in the second function that keeps if from finding any elements.

Working code: http://jsfiddle.net/7j3mk/7/

```
$("#slider div.popup").hover(
  function() {
    var ind = $(this).index();
    $("#slider div.popup").each(function() {
      if ($(this).index() != ind) {
        //fades all other .popup divs
        $(this).animate({ opacity: 0 });
      }
    });
  }, function() {
    var ind = $(this).index();
    $("#slider div.popup").each(function() {
      if ($(this).index() != ind) {
        //unfades all other .popup divs
        $(this).animate({ opacity: 1 });
      }
    });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the hover function wrong. You pass in two functions to the hover, the first is for the mouse enter, and the second for mouse out. The hover function works some what like this:

```
$("#slider div.popup").hover(
    function() {
        //this is run when the mouse hovers over
    },
    function () {
        //this is run when the mouse leaves
    }
);
```

You can't have any over code inside the hover() besides those two functions, so in your example the line

```
var ind = $(this).index();
```

Is causing the error. I suggest you read up further on [hover() on the jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something like

```
$(this).addClass("hover");

$("#slider div.popup:not(.hover)").each(function(){
    $(this).animate({
        opacity:0   
    });
})
```

Inside your hover function. Take a look at the docs - http://api.jquery.com/hover/ - you pass 2 functions - one to be executed 'onmouseover' and the other to be executed 'onmouseout'.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/RL6s8/:

```
var $sliderDivs = $("#slider div.popup");

$sliderDivs.hover(function() {

    var hoveredIndex = $(this).index();
    $sliderDivs.each(function() {

        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.index() !== hoveredIndex) {

            //fades all other .popup divs
            $this.animate.stop(true,true).({ opacity: 0 }, 500);

        }

    });

}, function() {

    var hoveredIndex = $(this).index();
    $sliderDivs.each(function() {

        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.index() !== hoveredIndex) {

            //unfades all other .popup divs
            $this.animate.stop(true,true).({ opacity: 1 }, 500);

        }

    });

});
```

**EDIT:**

Added `.stop(true,true)` and `500`ms to the jQuery to eliminate infinite queuing.

Comment: Doing it this way eliminates some of the needless re-jQuery-ifying (if that's a word, lol) that other answers are using. I find it much better performance wise to store my jQuery'd items in variables and then using those variables instead.